# How to keep a side menu open

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get my side menu to stay open when a user clicks one of the child menu items. For example if I hover over section 1, section 2 is displayed and if I click on section 2 then section 2 content is shown, but section 1 is still open and doesn't close unless I click on section 4, which is a child of section 3.

My problem is that I can't get it to stay open when the child menu item is open.

My html

```
<div id="second-menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse menu_two">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav inside-nav">
        <li class="sub_menu">
            <a href="#">Section 1</a>
            <ul class="sidenav_wrapper">
                <li class="sidenav_item sidenavlast">
                    <a href="#">Section 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="active_sub_menu">
            <a href="#">Section 3</a>
            <ul class="sidenav_wrapper">
                <li class="sidenav_item">
                    <a href="#">Section 4</a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidenav_item">
                    <a href="#">Section 5</a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidenav_item">
                    <a href="#">Section 6</a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidenav_item sidenavlast">
                    <a href="#">Section 7</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub_menu">
            <a href="#">Section 8</a>
            <ul class="sidenav_wrapper">
                <li class="sidenav_item">
                    <a href="#">Section 9</a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidenav_item">
                    <a href="#">Section 10</a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidenav_item sidenavlast">
                    <a href="#">Section 11</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My js

```
    $('ul.navbar-nav li').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find('.sidenav_wrapper:first').css('display','block');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find('.sidenav_wrapper:first').css('display','none');  
    }
);
```

my css

```
.menu_two {
    border-left: 16px solid #dfdfdf;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.sidenav_wrapper {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e7ecf5;
    border-left: 6px solid #8fb8e6;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle:[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9kw03b5a/)

Comment: If I may ask, why don't you add in a button so that the user can decide when to open or close the menu? That way you can prevent a lot of frustration for your users

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

I've added a jQuery `.click()` function to your fiddle. This function adds an `.open` class to the current `.sidenav_wrapper` and removes the `.open` class from an other `.sidenav_wrapper` when a link is selected in a `.sidenav_wrapper`. The `e.preventDefault()` prevents the default action of the hyperlink. This won't take the browser to an other URL.

**CSS**

```
.open {
    display: block !important;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.sidenav_wrapper').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.sidenav_wrapper').removeClass('open');
    $(this).addClass('open');
});
```

> Check this in the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9kw03b5a/1/)

Comment: Did you try it without the `e_preventDefault()`?  http://jsfiddle.net/9kw03b5a/3/

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working. All I did was made a php loop that made a menu item active and created an active class and used that class to display block.